# What is difference between Web API and Web Service in general not in terms of any language

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I am very confused with this two words. I frequently use this two words anywhere.
So I want to know the exact difference rather than the language oriented.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is Web services are `SOAP services(WSDL)` and `WEBAPI is HTTP service(REST)`.
As per your need you can choose on of them. Typically you can use `XML/JSON` as input/output for `WebAPI`

Comment: i can use same XML/JSON format for web service as well @Rakesh

Comment: Yes, but the best way is WebAPI. Because it is light weight.